# Headphone sound not working unless reinsert headphone

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

I have a computer case with asus z270a and I install ubuntu 16.04,every time I reboot the computer my headphone dosen't word,but if I pluck the earphone and reinsert it to the computer it will have sound again!Is there anyway to solve the problem?